# `out` variable unassigned... unless the condition is inline?

Tags: c#, out

I'm trying to understand what the C# compiler's rules are for deciding when an `out` variable was assigned.

Here's one example that baffles me. Let's assume we have a `Dictionary<>`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Let's start with a simple condition: this compiles.

```
var found = dict.TryGetValue("b", out var val);
if(found)
{
    Console.WriteLine(val); //no problem
}
```

If the condition is slightly more complicated, it's a compile error:

```
var aBool = true;
var found = aBool && dict.TryGetValue("b", out var val);
if(found)
{
    Console.WriteLine(val); //use of unassigned local variable val
}
```

OK, so I guess the compiler doesn't deal with logical operators in this case.
...but if we move the *exact same condition inline*, it's all rainbows again:

```
var aBool = true;
if(aBool && dict.TryGetValue("b", out var val))
{
    Console.WriteLine(val); //compiles fine
}
```

Why?

Comment: It's worth noting that `&` works and `&&` does not, e.g. `var found = aBool & dict.TryGetValue("b", out var val);` is OK. With `&&` the call to `TryGetValue` might not take place due to [short circuit evaluation](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/short-circuit-evaluation-in-c-sharp/) and therefore `val` might remain uninitialized..

Answer (score 4):

The compiler cannot guarantee that the variable `val` is initialized. In that context, `aBool` is some non-constant boolean expression. Depending on the value of `aBool`, `val` may or may not be initialized since the expression may not be evaluated due to the short circuiting `&&`.

To help the compiler out, you would have to make `aBool` constant so the compiler can then perform the full analysis. If `aBool == true`, `val` is definitely initialized. If `false`, `val` is definitely not initialized. Flow analysis could then determine that `found` will be set to a value consistent with the state of the `val` variable.

```
const bool aBool = true;
...
```

The reason why the second case is fine, `val` is only ever used in the body of the `if` statement. And the body will only be entered if both `aBool` is `true` and the `TryGetValue()` call succeeds (and consequently `val` is initialized).